# Problema ao usar addEventListener em loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Após ter criado uma série de tags `<button>`, a ideia era o botão mudar de cor caso o usuário passe o mouse em qualquer um deles. O problema é que não funciona e não sei o porquê. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Meu código JavaScript:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button") //vetor de 38 botoes

for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) //percorre o vetor buttons
{
    buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", destacaButton(buttons[i]), false) //adiciona um evento em cada button
}

function destacaButton(button)
{
    button.style.backgroundColor = black; //pinta o fundo de preto se passar o mouse
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) espera receber uma [*função*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es) em seu segundo argumento. No entanto, note que você está **chamando** a função (antes de passá-la para o `addEventListener`). Veja "[Chamando Funções](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es#Calling_functions)" na documentação para saber mais.

Por conta disso, ao invés de passar a função ao `addEventListener`, você está passando o *retorno* da função que você chamou. Como a função não retorna nada, está passando `undefined`.

Você precisa passar a referência da função (o nome, por exemplo):

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", destacaButton, false);
}

function destacaButton() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

Algumas modificações no código:

- Transformei `black` em uma string, assim: `"black"`. Manter do jeito que estava (somente o identificador `black`) provavelmente causaria um `ReferenceError`.
- Troquei o parâmetro `button` pelo `this`. Quando o `addEventListener` chama a função de *callback*, ele associa o `this` da função ao elemento que causou o evento. Nesse caso, será o próprio botão.

Um exemplo funcional:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", destacaButton, false);
}

function destacaButton() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

```html
<button>Botão 0</button> <button>Botão 1</button>
<button>Botão 2</button> <button>Botão 3</button>
<button>Botão 3</button> <button>Botão 5</button>
<button>Botão 6</button> <button>Botão 7</button>
<button>Botão 8</button> <button>Botão 9</button>
```

Comment: Caraca, perfeito! Entendi, perfeitamente. Muitíssimo obrigado

Answer (score 2):

O `addEventListener` uma `function`
e não não a chamada do seu método, por isso está executando aquela `function` no momento em que você atribui;

A forma correta seria:

```
  buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    destacaButton(buttons[i]);
  });
```

Que a partir do ES6, com o suporte à funções anônimas pode escrito como `()=>`

```
buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseout", () => destacaButton(buttons[i]));
```

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button") //vetor de 38 botoes

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    destacaButton(buttons[i]);
  });
  buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseout", () => restauraButton(buttons[i]));

}

let destacaButton = function(button) {
  button.style.color = 'white';
  button.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}

let restauraButton = function(button) {
  button.style.color = '';
  button.style.backgroundColor = '';
}
```

```html
<button>teste</button>
<button>teste</button>
<button>teste</button>
<button>teste</button>
<button>teste</button>
```

Porém... se o objetivo é só aparência o correto seria deixar o CSS resolver isso...